# Infinite recursive languages and infinite regular languages.

Tags: computability, regular-language

Could the following statement be correct?

"Every infinite recursive language has as a subset an infinite regular language."

Comment: I don't think there is an infinite regular subset of the set of strings of prime length.

Comment: Let $(A_i : i \in \omega)$ be a uniformly computable sequence infinite sets that is, so that the predicate $P(n,i) \equiv n \in A_i$ is computable. Then it is easy to construct an infinite recursive set $X$ that does not have any of the sets $A_i$ as a subset.  In fact, we can ensure that $X \Delta A_i$ is infinite for each set $A_i$ in the sequence.

Comment: @Thomas: yes, this follows from the pumping lemma.

Answer (score 2):

No. Call a language [*lacunary*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lacunary_function) if it is infinite and the gaps between the distinct lengths of words goes to infinity; for example, the language of words whose length is square.

By the pumping lemma, no lacunary language is regular (or context-free), and every infinite subset of a lacunary language is lacunary.

Comment: Someone care to explain the downvote?